# How to wait for EventHandler being triggered in UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, event-handling, windows-10-iot-core

I made a simple app in UWP and I'm having trouble with the EventHandlers not being triggered... I made the same app in Core.NET and it works great if I add "Console.ReadLine()" at the end of the main function so it seems like the thread of the main function dies before EventHandlers can be triggered.

Is there a way, in UWP, for the instance to stay alive a while (ie: timeout) to give a chance for the EventHandlers to be triggered.

Note: This is an example of the problem; the real context will happen in the reception of a web request.

Here's the code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        test();
    }

    private async void test() {

        Client DiscoverClient;
        DiscoverClient = new Client();
        DiscoverClient.DeviceHandler += Client_DeviceHandler;
        await DiscoverClient.DiscoverAsync();
    }

    static private void Client_DeviceHandler(object sender, BroadlinkDevice device)
    {
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want x = 0 e.g. the event handler to be executed before `DiscoverAsync()` is called? Since there are multiple ways of achieving what you want (using `Thread.Sleep()`, using a spinlock, etc.)

Comment: The "x =0" if just some code so I could put a breakpoint. The expected behavior is that DiscoverAsync searches for devices on the network and then Client_DeviceHandler is called for each one that is found. The problem is that the handler is never called.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem as I am not clear about the definition of client class. Could you provide me with more details about the client class?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I'm trying to integrate "device discovery" from the code at https://github.com/kemalincekara/Broadlink.NET into a UWP webservice (deployed on WIn10 IOT Core on a Raspberry) that receives web requests. I wanna make a custom bridge between my phone and the device on my home network...

Comment: Maybe you could try to use Deferral class. Add a statement var deferral = new Deferral(OnTaskCompleted); at the beginning of test() and add a statement deferral.Complete(); at the end of the test(). OnTaskCompleted is a method to be called upon completion of the deferral.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I just tried and it doesnt change anything... DiscoverAsync does not block the execution of the code (even with the await). So the code falls on the deferral.Complete line after a few seconds.

Comment: Is it possible that the `DiscoverClient` found no devices?

Comment: No, the device was accessible and discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```cs
await DiscoverClient.DiscoverAsync()
```

you could use

```cs
_ = DiscoverClient.DiscoverAsync().Result
```

This enforces `test()` to wait for `DiscoverAsync()` to return.

`.Result` may only be used if the return type is not `void`, so you could just let `DiscoverAsync()` return a boolean when it is finished. The discard is then used to have an assignment that makes the constructor block until `DiscoverAsync()` is done.

Comment: DiscoverAsync returns a Task so there is no "Result" property... :-( Is there a way to do something like that with the Task methods? I tried the "Wait" method but it does'nt work either... If that can help, the code for DiscoveryAsync is located in here: https://github.com/kemalincekara/Broadlink.NET

Comment: that is weird, since in my tests using `await` will return before the method is done while `.Wait()` will only return after the function is done since this method will block the current thread synchronously.

Comment: I'm no expert when it comes to EventHandler... Maybe there's a way using threads? Maybe a solution similar to the one I used for the Core.NET version exixts for UWP? Id dosen't have to be that pretty; just has to be working :-)

Comment: Maybe you could add breakpoints to ClientSocket_MessageReceived method and view if the app steps into the method. If the app steps into the ClientSocket_MessageReceived method, you need to check if the value of response is null.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to integrate the library mentioned in your comment into my UWP app, it will throw 'Access Denied' exption when call method `GetActiveTcpConnections`(line 60 in Network.cs). Since that the event Client_DeviceHandler will not be triggerred. Please see this issue([issue#24369](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24369)) in github.

This document shows how to use socket in UWP. You may refer the server sample to modify or implement the feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

Answer (score 0):

I tryed multiple ways found on the internet (some using sockets) but I did'nt find a working solution...

I ended up using a workaround: looping through ip searching for the device's hostname. Since the IP only changes when my router is restarded, the discovery process is rarely needed so even if it's a little on the heavy side, it's quite ok for me :-)

Thanks for you help guys